# Creating a database using Hadoop on AWS via Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, aws-sdk

I'm working on an assignment for my university where I need to implement something using Hadoop on AWS.
In order to implement said thing, I want to use a relational database like MySQL.

I have read and saw I can in fact use MySQL as a RDS with AWS, however I didn't understood how to go about doing that with Hadoop and on top of that, with Java SDK.

Basically, after a few steps, I receive files in which each line looks like so:

```
(A, B, C) num1 num2
```

I want to perform an additional step that will create the a database in which each A is a new table, each B is a new row, and C, num1 and num2 are cells in that row.

I need this in order to later perform SELECT and JOIN queries on those tables.

Is this even possible? If so, can someone please help me with an example or a checklist of things I must do to create and then use the database?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

In order to clarify, I want to create a database like MySQL, and then add items to it via the Hadoop step. for example, if my mappers receive the line I wrote above from my file, then for each A they will create a new table and send to the reducers: key - A, value - B, C, num1, num2.

Then, each reducer will receive a table as key, and all elements to fill it with as values, so for each value (aka B, C, num1, num2) it will create a row B in that table, and fill it with C, num1, num2 cells.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop isn't a database. The project consists of storage and execution via HDFS (which you're not using if the data is in S3), YARN, and MapReduce. Out of the box, there is no easy joining or SQL-like things it can do. For that, you at least need Hive, which can sit on top of MySQL.

If all you want is SQL, then in Hadoop-land you can use SparkSQL directly against S3 datasets. Or you can stay in AWS-land and use Athena.

However, if your dataset isn't that large to begin with (even up to 100+ GB), then using MySQL on RDS will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, @cricket_007. I know that Hadoop isn't a database. My question was how can I use a database and build it during an Hadoop step.

Comment: Still not understanding what you're asking... What is a "Hadoop step"? Let's say you had setup RDS, then you could use Sqoop to pull that data **into** Hadoop HDFS (or Hive, or HBase), but Hadoop is not "on top of" any database itself, and has no dependencies on using something like MySQL

Comment: Thanks for trying to help and I'm sorry I'm unclear, I'll try once again. Say I have a RDS on AWS. Say I also have large files sitting on S3. Is there any way I can perform a job in Hadoop that consist of a map stage and a reduce stage, in order to read the lines of those files and add them to my database in a form of a table or a row inside that table?

Comment: You don't need to use Hadoop for that at all, though. You can use SparkSQL, as mentioned, to read from S3 and write into RDS... But AWS has plenty of tools just for these use-cases. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-copys3tords.html  Or you could just put a Hive table over S3 and forget RDS, but it wouldn't be as fast, and you should have several 100 GB to fit that use-case